# Azure Pipeline Release have been stuck at Downloading Artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-task

The past week our pipeline would get stuck at the Downloading Artifact. One day I would just let it go since it was late and it went back to normal. Now the issue pop up again and I can't get deployment going.

Stuck for 11 minutes. Usually done less than a minute

[image]

Nothing in the log. It keeps just spinning.

Comment: Is it a private agent or a hosted agent?

Comment: Does this happen only for one pipeline?

Comment: What about using the [Download Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) or [Download Pipeline Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops)?  Do they have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

This happen sometimes with Azure agent. sometimes it's an intermittent error.there is a step call UniversalPackage download can also be used.